# How to state number of cpus in autoscaler config.yaml for specific node

Tags: multiprocessing, ray

I am trying to find the command for the config.yml for ray autoscaler

I know there are max_workers but that considers the cluster as a whole. I want to limit the number of cpus launched on each worker node.

for example:

```
worker_node:
            max_cpus: 3
Head_node:
            max_cpus: 4
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The number of CPUs per worker is determined by the worker's configuration which is provider specific. This is what the `node_config` field is for. For example, with AWSm if you wanted to specify a 4 CPU machine you would do something like

```
available_node_types:
    cpu_4_ondemand:
        node_config:
            InstanceType: m4.xlarge
        min_workers: 1
        max_workers: 5
```

notice the `InstanceType` field, which is specific to EC2 (it's 4 cpus because that's how many cpus are on a m4.xlarge instance).

For Kubernetes, you would place a CRD in the `node_config` field. For example

```
node_config:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
        # Automatically generates a name for the pod with this prefix.
        generateName: ray-worker-

        # Must match the worker node service selector above if a worker node
        # service is required.
        labels:
            component: ray-worker
    spec:
          resources:
              requests:
                  cpu: 4000m
                  memory: 512MiB
```

For more information, you may be interested in taking a look at the provider specific examples in the ray repo. For example, here are the aws examples: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/tree/master/python/ray/autoscaler/aws